# How do I decide whether an Event is a Conditional Probability or an Intersection?

Tags: probability

<sub>My question is based on Example 1.9, p 22, *Introduction to Probability (1 Ed, 2002) by Bertsekas, Tsitsiklis.</sub>

> Define the event $A$ = {an aircraft is present} and $R$ = {the radar registers an aircraft presence}. Express the following events in terms of $A$, $R$, and/or their complements.
>
> $\begin{align}
>   & \text{(i) The radar correctly registers an aircraft presence}\text{.} \\ 
>  & \text{(ii) The radar falsely registers an aircraft presence}\text{.} \\ 
>  & \text{(iii) A false alarm} \\ 
>  & \text{(iv) A missed detection} \\ 
> \end{align}$

How do I decide whether each event should be symbolised as a Conditional Probability or Intersection? To wit, how do I decide and disambiguate between:

\begin{array}{l|l}
    For (i)            & Pr(A|R) \; \text{ or } \; Pr(R|A) \; \text{ or } \; Pr(A \cap R)    \quad ?       \\
    For (ii) and (iii) & Pr(A^C|R) \; \text{ or } \; \Pr(R|A^C)\ \; \text{ or } \; Pr(A^C \cap R)  \quad ?    \\
    For (iv)           & Pr(A|R^C) \; \text{ or } \;Pr(R^C|A) \; \text{ or } \; Pr(A \cap R^C)  \quad ?     \\
    \end{array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the aircraft is present, and the radar registers "presence", then it is the case that the radar *correctly* registers an aircraft. Thus,
   $A\cap R.$
2. If the aircraft is *not* present, and the radar registers "presence", then the radar falsely registers an aircraft. Thus $\bar A\cap R$.
3. A false alarm occurs when the radar registers "presence", but there is no aircraft. This is the same as 2.
4. A missed detection occurs when an aircraft is present, but the radar registers nothing. Thus, $A\cap\bar R$.

   ---

For any of them, it does not make sense to use the symbol $|$, since nothing was given. You use the $|$ when there are key phrases like:

- Given that $X$, what is the probability of $Y$? $\implies P(Y|X)$
- You are told that $Y$, what is chance that $X$ will happen?$\implies P(X|Y)$
- You know that $Y$ did not occur, what is probability that $X$ does not occur? $\implies P(\bar X|\bar Y)$

Additionally, in the exercises, there is no mention of probability or chance, so you do not use $P(\,)$.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you decide to eliminate the other two probabilities for 1 and 2? I still cannot disambiguate the three possible choices.

Comment: @LePressentiment I have updated my answer.

Comment: +1. I hope that others will upvote your answer (as I did), which I find as equally as beneficient and helpful as the others.